# How to have endless scrolling ground at an angle with Swift and Spritekit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, side-scroller

I am trying to implement an endless scrolling ground with Swift and Spritekit. I managed to get the scrolling ground to work if the ground is a flat surface. But I want the ground to be on a decline like it is going down a hill. How can I do this? Here is the code I currently have:

```
func createGround() {
    for i in 0...2 {
        let grounds = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 600, height: 200))
        grounds.name = "Ground"
        grounds.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5,y: 0.5)
        grounds.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * grounds.size.width, y: -300)

        self.addChild(grounds)
    }
}

func moveGround() {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "Ground", using: ({
        (node, error) in

        node.position.x -= 6
        node.position.y += 1

        if node.position.x < -((self.scene?.size.width)!) {
            node.position.x += (self.scene?.size.width)! * 3
            node.position.y =
                -400
        }
    }))
}
```

This creates the ground and scrolls them through the screen at an angle, but the ground nodes do not line up with each other. I imagine I will need some trigonometric function to make them line up? Here is what is currently looks like:

[image]

The white rectangles are my ground nodes. The grey is just a placeholder ground node which is not moving and I plan on deleting once I get the scrolling ground working.

Comment: You know,  I have never tried this, but have you thought about making it sideways and just rotating the entire scene?

Comment: Hmmm. I haven't thought of that but that could work and make everything more simple once I add other objects into the scene. I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: I don't know how SKPhysicsWorld would play a role,  you may have to adjust the gravity vector